# Por que se escreve "máquina de Turing", "algoritmo de Grover" ao mesmo tempo que se escreve "algoritmo Monte Carlo" e "algoritmo Las Vegas"?

Tags: gramática, uso-de-palavras, tradução-inglês, tradução, termos-em-inglês

Note que em "máquina de Turing" usualmente não se quer dizer uma máquina de propriedade de Alan M. Turing, mas apenas refere-se ao conceito criado por ele.  Portanto "de Turing" aqui tem função sintática de adjetivo.  Não é um complemento nominal.

Todavia, quando se trata de um algoritmo Monte Carlo, não se diz "algoritmo de Monte Carlo", mas sim "algoritmo Monte Carlo" bem como "algoritmo Las Vegas".  (São tipos de algoritmos.  Um algoritmo Monte Carlo pode terminar sem uma resposta ou com uma resposta incorreta.  Um algoritmo Las Vegas sempre termina com a resposta correta.)

Eis evidências do uso de "algoritmo Monte Carlo" e "algoritmo Las Vegas". Note que as duas evidências são livros traduzidos e tudo indica que a tradução é feita por gente competente.

```
Algoritmos 
Sanjoy Dasgupta, Christos Papadimitriou, Umesh Vazirani
https://goo.gl/DWZDbp

Matemática Discreta e suas Aplicações 
Kenneth H. Rosen
https://goo.gl/EdQuis
```

Já exemplos de uso de "máquina de Turing" estão por toda parte.

Answer (score 3):

Sumário: Os dois primeiros são específicos (e são nomes de pessoas), os dois últimos não são específicos, mas sim denotam classes de algoritmos.

---

Na verdade, a premissa da pergunta não parece estar de todo correta:

- o Glossário de Termos Estatísticos ([pdf1](https://www.ine.pt/ngt_server/attachfileu.jsp?look_parentBoui=211277003&att_display=n&att_download=y), [pdf2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjx5pyM_pPgAhXK1SwKHWxODyoQFjAAegQIFBAC&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.ine.pt%2Fngt_server%2Fattachfileu.jsp%3Flook_parentBoui%3D211277131%26att_display%3Dn%26att_download%3Dy&usg=AOvVaw01HxplFAjclf23EIyBeZL3)) do [Instituto Nacional de Estatística](https://www.ine.pt/xportal/xmain?xpid=INE&xpgid=ine_publicacoes&PUBLICACOESpub_boui=211276307&PUBLICACOESmodo=2&xlang=pt) de Portugal lista "Método **de** Monte-Carlo" como tradução de *Monte-Carlo Method*  (pg 33);
- o verbete correspondente da Wikipedia tem o título [Método **de** Monte Carlo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Monte_Carlo);
- no (ainda modesto) repositório [EduCAPES](https://educapes.capes.gov.br/) encontram-se 18 textos com o "de", e apenas 3 sem a preposição;
- uma busca cursiva por livros sobre o assunto também revela o uso frequente da expressão com o "de" ([um exemplo](https://books.google.de/books?id=Vuo5AwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA68&dq=%22m%C3%A9todo%20de%20monte%20carlo%22%20%22estat%C3%ADstico%22&pg=PA68#v=onepage&q=%22m%C3%A9todo%20de%20monte%20carlo%22%20%22estat%C3%ADstico%22&f=false));
- uma pesquisa no Google por ambas as expressões (a adição do termo "estatístico" visa a evitar resultados em espanhol) revela números similares de *hits*:

[image]

Ou seja, o uso de "método **de** Monte-Carlo" é certamente estabelecido e, em textos técnicos, mostra-se mais comum que a versão sem a preposição.

Ainda assim, é interessante questionar porque pode-se (pode-se?) omitir o "de" em "método de Monte-Carlo" mas não em "máquina de Turing". Sem a ambição de dar uma resposta final, faço algumas observações:

- Não usamos nomes de pessoas como adjetivos em português, ou seja, não se omite o "de" em "quadro de Picasso", "poema de Drummond", "demônio de Maxwell", etc., e, claro, Turing e Grover são pessoas. Veja que aqui há uma diferença importante com relação ao inglês, em que o fenômeno da conversão do genitivo (possessivo - "de") em atributivo ("adjetivo") é comum, e inclusive pode ser vista no próprio "Turing machine" (embora, curiosamente, no caso de Grover, até o [termo original em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grover's_algorithm) use o possessivo, talvez por ser mais recente). Inclusive, eu não me espantaria se expressões como "método Monte-Carlo" fossem, em alguns casos, anglicismos.
- Por outro lado, quando um nome passa a denotar uma categoria/classe/tipo, podemos ter a omissão de qualificadores como "do tipo" e acabamos com expressões como "vaso (da dinastia) Ming" e "queijo (do tipo) Minas"; e, dado que o método de Monte-Carlo é na verdade uma classe de métodos, ao invés de um método específico, é de fato apropriado se falar de "método (do tipo [de]) Monte-Carlo.

Também os *algoritmos* (de?) Monte Carlo constituem uma classe, como colocado de maneira explícita nos verbetes da Wikipedia sobre algoritmos (de) [Atlantic City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_City_algorithm), [Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm) e [Las Vegas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Las_Vegas_algorithm). Vale notar o uso da preposição "de" no francês ([*Algorithme de Monte-Carlo*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Monte-Carlo)) e da palavra "tipo" no tcheco ([*Algoritmus typu Monte Carlo*](https://cs.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmus_typu_Monte_Carlo)).

Portanto, também para o caso dos algoritmos, me parece que a omissão da preposição subentende o uso dos nomes para denotar classes.

Essa [página sobre o algoritmo de Rabin-Karp](https://www.ime.usp.br/~pf/estruturas-de-dados/aulas/rabin-karp.html) do IME-USP usa explicitamente o termo "tipo":

> algoritmos do tipo Monte Carlo e do tipo Las Vegas

Como curiosidade, vale notar também que nela se encontram (minha numeração):

> 1. Algoritmo de Rabin-Karp para busca de substring
> 2. O algoritmo Rabin-Karp compara [...]
> 3. implementação do algoritmo RK [...]

em que há a preposição "de" no título da página (1), que no entanto é omitida (2) no texto: o que tanto pode ser um *typo*, quanto um anglicismo, quanto o simples uso de "Rabin-Karp" como nome do algoritmo - caso mais provável, dado que se trata de um algoritmo específico, e que esse uso aparentemente volta a se repetir em (3), com as iniciais "RK".

Comment: Obrigado pela excelente resposta, mas note que "Método de Monte Carlo" é uma técnica estatística, algo bem diferente de um "algoritmo (de) Monte Carlo".  Realmente o método é usualmente escrito "de Monte Carlo", mas ainda não encontrei instância em que se escreve algoritmo "de Monte Carlo".  (Bem como algoritmo (de) Las Vegas.)

Adoraria ter uma fonte formal que relata exatamente seu último ponto --- quando um nome passa a denotar uma categoria.

Comment: @user4587, [*algorítmo de Monte Carlo* (Google)](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22algoritmo+de+monte+carlo%22&oq=%22&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l3j69i57j69i59.1748j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) é fácil de encontrar, em textos técnicos oriundos de universidades brasilieiras e outra instituições.

Comment: @user4587 Importante observação, a verdade é que eu não tinha tratado do caso dos algoritmos. E concordo contigo sobre (quase) não se encontrar "algoritmo de Monte Carlo" - muitos dos *hits* do Google em que usa essa expressão são em grande parte teses e dissertação em que escreve-se "algoritmo", mas quer-se dizer "método". Mas creio ter complementado a resposta atendendo a teu pedido - com referências ao uso do "algoritmo de Monte Carlo" como categoria.

Answer (score 0):

Há uma diferença que não determina se há um *de* ou não, mas que poderá influenciar. O *de* em *máquina de Turing* e *algoritmo de Grover* indica origem: a [máquina de Turing](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A1quina_de_Turing) foi inventada por Alan Turing, e o [algoritmo de Grover](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_de_Grover) foi criado por Lov Grover. Do mesmo modo, o *de* indica origem em [*equilíbrio de Nash*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equil%C3%ADbrio_de_Nash) (conceptualizado por John Nash), [*teorema* ou *regra de Bayes*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teorema_de_Bayes) (Thomas Bayes), [*ótimo de Pareto*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Efici%C3%AAncia_de_Pareto) (Vilfredo Pareto) ou [*lei de Say*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lei_de_Say) (Jean-Baptiste Say).

Agora, os nome *algoritmo de Monte Carlo* e *algoritmo de Las Vegas* seriam perfeitamente possíveis, mas o *de* seria um mero elemento de ligação sem qualquer significado, como em *cidade de Lisboa* ou *pobre do rapaz*. É possível que isto facilite a supressão do *de*.

Pode facilitar, mas não determina. Nós temos *algoritmo Monte Carlo*, mas [*método* e *estudo **de** Monte Carlo*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Monte_Carlo). Mas a relação do método e do algoritmo com Monte Carlo é essencialmente a mesma. O método (no original em inglês, *Monte Carlo method*) foi desenvolvido por John von Neuman e Stanislaw Ulam em Los Alamos, Estados Unidos. A [Wikipedia em inglês](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_method) diz que o nome foi sugerido devido a um tio de Ulam jogar habitualmente no casino de Monte Carlo, e atribui a origem do nome do [algoritmo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monte_Carlo_algorithm) à mesma sugestão. Eu já conhecia o método, e sempre pensei que o nome se devesse ao facto de o método assentar em processos aleatórios, e é isso que diz a [Wikipédia em português](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9todo_de_Monte_Carlo) e em [francês](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%A9thode_de_Monte-Carlo). A [Wikipédia em francês](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algorithme_de_Monte-Carlo) diz ser esta também a razão do nome do algoritmo, que envolve também processos aleatórios. Outros dois algoritmos relacionados, o [algoritmo Las Vegas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algoritmo_Las_Vegas) e o algoritmo (de?) Atlantic City [(Wikipedia em inglês)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlantic_City_algorithm) foram também buscar os nomes a cidades conhecidas pelos seus casinos.

Portanto termos o *de* no nome do método mas não no do algoritmo deve-se ao desenvolvimento independente de tradições particulares e não é determinado por regra geral da língua portuguesa. A língua permite as duas opções.

Mesmo quando tem significado, o *de* é por vezes suprimido. O [motor diesel](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_a_diesel) foi inventado por Rudolf Diesel. Atualmente *diesel*, com inicial minúscula, refere-se ao combustível, o que torna o nome *motor diesel* uma anomalia; deveria ser *motor a diesel*, que também se usa, mas parece ser menos comum. A anomalia explica-se, a meu ver, por *motor diesel* ser o descendente de *motor Diesel*, com maiúscula, que nós encontramos na imprensa brasileira a partir de 1903 (exemplos de [1903](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=364568_09&pesq=motor%20diesel&pasta=ano%20190), [1906](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=388653&pesq=motor%20diesel&pasta=ano%20190) e [1907](http://memoria.bn.br/DocReader/DocReader.aspx?bib=008567&pesq=motor%20diesel&pasta=ano%20190)), onde *Diesel* é o nome do inventor, sem o *de*, embora o *de* fizesse sentido.

Outro exemplo da minha área é a [função de Cobb-Douglas](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_Cobb-Douglas), cuja a aplicação à Economia se deve a Charles Cobb e Paul Douglas. É comum dizermos *função de Cobb-Douglas*, mas é igualmente comum dizermos, e encontra-se em livros, simplesmente *função Cobb-Douglas*. E enquanto eu posso dizer *função de Cobb-Douglas*, digo normalmente *função de produção Cobb-Douglas* e não *de Cobb-Douglas*; talvez por aversão à repetição da preposição. Mas nunca omito nenhum *de* em *função de produção de Leontief* (mas já vi quem o fizesse); chamem-me incoerente.

Conclusão. Haverá maior tendência a manter o *de* quando este tem significado e não é só elemento de ligação. Mas haver um *de* ou não acaba por ser determinado pela evolução de cada nome em resultado das preferências dos falantes, preferências que parecem variar de caso para caso.